# Change property in a View before displaying it with Vaadin

Tags: java, view, vaadin, navigator

I use Vaadin 7. I want to change a property in view before going into it. When I click on a link in my first View it redirect me to the second View with a parameter in the URL like this :

```
<myDomain>:<myport>/vaadinApp/#!SecondView/?id=myid
```

Now what I did is the following :

```
SecondView second = new SecondView();
getNavigator().addView(SecondView.NAME, second);
```

And I added a listener on change view:

```
getNavigator().addViewChangeListener(new ViewChangeListener() {

  private Map<String, String> queryMap;

  @Override
  public boolean beforeViewChange(ViewChangeEvent event) {

    //here I get my parameter (its working)
    if (!event.getParameters().equals("")) {
      queryMap = getQueryMap(event.getParameters().replace("?", ""));
    }

    String newViewName = event.getViewName();

    if(newViewName.equals(SecondView.NAME)){

      System.out.println("In Second VIEW : ");
      if (queryMap != null && !queryMap.get("id").equals("")) {
        System.out.println("IF FOUND !! => " + queryMap.get("id"));

        second.setId(queryMap.get("id"));
        System.out.println("SET =>" + second.getId());
      }
    }
    ....
```

Now when I run my application, in the console I get this:

```
IF FOUND !! => activiti$4077
SET =>activiti$4077
ID : null
```

That means that I get the parameter, I changed it in the `View` but when it display the view I get `id = null` which means that actually it doesn't change anything. Is there anything wrong with my code ? Help!

Comment: i'd rather only put checks for security in the beforeViewChange (e.g. is the current user allowed to access the id) and then use the enter() of the second view to setup the view.  i would assume, that the `second` you hold in the  handler is not the same (vaadin's session/thread might rob you of this - and should it not also be declared final?  but i am not sure there, been a while since my last java code...)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely question mark in your parameters is causing the problem. Try to remove it (and update your parameter handling accordingly) `/vaadinApp/#!SecondView/?id=myid` -> `/vaadinApp/#!SecondView/id=myid`.

`?` is used with query string parameters but parameters in this case are just part of the URI fragment.

Comment: There is no problem with the parameters. I can actually get the paramaters and values but I can't assign it to the property `id` in my `View`.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your problem. Are you sure you are setting the id for the correct SecondView instance? Can't you just do the parameter handling inside the enter method in SecondView?

Comment: Actually this is what I did at the end. Thanks !